# launch ElasticSearch in Docker Plesk

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, plesk

I have the following problem when launching elasticsearch in the docker plesk obsidian, how and where should I change this parameter, I have not used docker before.

Thanks if someone can help!

ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed

[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured

Comment: I'm not familiar with "es in docker plesk obsidian", but if you are not using this for production env, easiest way would be to run it as per a dev environment with this command option "-e discovery.type=single-node". Otherwise, you may want to see this as it should give you a pretty accurate idea of how to run es with docker in a pr env. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.5/docker.html

Comment: I understand what I need to do. The problem is that I don’t know where and how to change the launch configuration (path). Due to the fact that I did not use docker
 
And plesk

Comment: ok. did you see this? https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/obsidian/administrator-guide/75823/ it is the first thing a google search returned by searching "plesk docker change enviromental variable" It seems like plesk has its own way of changing env. variables in docker. With this guide and the previous guide, you should be able to ajust the behaviour of es docker images in plesk.

Comment: thanks for helping me! Yes, I tried to set the parameter through the Plesk.
discovery_type = single-node
discovery.type = single-node
discovery.seed_hosts: ["n0", "n1", "n2"]

Plesk does not process points, but underlining does not produce results

Comment: The most amazing and incredible thing is if I create a container like this:

docker run -e "discovery.type = single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.0

Then the Plesk will show me the parameter normally (discovery.type =  single-node), but I can not specify it myself through the panel due to the fact that the points are prohibited??? 

How can I set parameter in created container (discovery.type =  single-node) from the console?